# Invoking PS script from C# code (Visual studio 2017)

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I am trying to invoke my PS script from C# code.

```
**PS code. -- Try.ps1**
Write-Host "HelloHost"
Write-Debug "HelloDebug"
Write-Output "HelloOutput"
echo "tofile" > $PSScriptRoot/a.txt

**C# code**

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

namespace TryitOut
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (PowerShell pshell = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                pshell.AddScript(path + "\\Try.ps1");
                IAsyncResult result = pshell.BeginInvoke();
                while (result.IsCompleted == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for PS script to finish...");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run "Try.ps1" independently it runs ok and creates a.txt ans shows console output as expected.
But, it not getting invoked/executed via this C# code.
**Question 1**. can you please help, what I am doing wrong?
**Q 2.** How can I see PS console output when invoking Try.ps1 via C# code

Thank you for your time :).

Comment: PM> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17134  165

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with output from the [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) object is done in two ways.  One is the direct return values of the `Invoke` call, and the other is via various [streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psdatastreams?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0).  In both cases, you are responsible for dealing with the data; the console does not automatically output them as when you run a script in the standard PowerShell window.  For example, to get the results from `Write-Object`, you can add the following to your `C#` code after your `while` loop:

```
foreach(PSObject pso in pshell.EndInvoke(result))
{
   Console.WriteLine(pso);
}
```

This works fine for the simple strings in your example, but for complex objects with multiple properties, you need to pull the individual properties by name.  For example:

```
string propValue = pso.Members["PropertyName"].Value.ToString();
```

Have a look at a previous answer of mine to see one way to convert complex objects to your own type:  [Dealing with CimObjects with PowerShell Inside C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51099688/dealing-with-cimobjects-with-powershell-inside-c-sharp/51103104#51103104)

Handle the debug, information, verbose, etc like this:

```
foreach(DebugRecord dbr in pshell.Streams.Debug)
{
   Console.WriteLine(dbr);
}
```

You will need to add this to the start of your script as well:

```
$DebugPreference = 'continue'
```