# vb.net casting a powershell output of objectmodel.collection(of PSObject) to a usable VB.net object

Tags: vb.net, powershell, casting, psobject

I'm using vb.net to remotely run some powershell commands, the output of the powershell.invoke is of the

```
ObjectModel.Collection(Of PSObject)
```

Type.

I'd like to cast these to usable vb.net class / collection. When I debug the code, and hover over the output / ObjectModel.Collection(Of PSObject) the data is shown as;

```
(0) {@{Name=John;Books=System.Collections.ArrayList}}
(1) {@{Name=Gerry;Books=System.Collections.ArrayList}}
```

How can I cast this into usable vb.net class/object?

I've try to make a custom class like so;

```
Class BookOwner
     public name as string
     public Books as systems.collections.arraylist
end class
```

and then cast it to the object;

```
dim MyBookOwner as BookOwner = trycast(Output(0).BaseObject, BookOwner)
```

output is of the objectmodel.collection(of PSObject) type.

But after the trycast the MyBookOwner stays empty.

How can I cast the ObjectModel.Collection(Of PSOject) to a usable vb.net object.

Comment: I don't think you can do a simple cast with the output. Here's one way to do it (C#, sorry) from a previous answer of mine: [Dealing with CimObjects with PowerShell inside C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51099688/dealing-with-cimobjects-with-powershell-inside-c-sharp/51103104#51103104)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I can see of the `PSObject` type and not having done any actual testing, I think that you may be able to do this:

```
Dim bookOwners As New List(Of BookOwner)

For Each pso In myPsObjectCollection
    Dim props = pso.Properties
    Dim name = CStr(props.Single(Function(pspi) pspi.Name = "Name").Value)
    Dim books = DirectCast(props.Single(Function(pspi) pspi.Name = "Books").Value, ArrayList)

    bookOwners.Add(New BookOwner With (.Name = name, .Books = books})
Next
```

Of course, you could also condense that into a LINQ query if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help jmcilhinney and boxdog, the information was very usefull.

To do a normal for each was jmcilhinney's idea, and to use the .members was in the example of boxdog. So I've combined both of your advise to end up with this;

```
dim AllBooks as new list(of BookOwner)

for each a as psobject in output
      dim abc as psobject = a.members("Books").value 
      AllBooks.add(new BookOwner with {.Name = A.Members("Name").value,
                                       .Books = tryCast(abc.BaseObject, ArrayList)})
next
```

I'm amazed that this doesn't work;

```
for each a as psobject in output
      AllBooks.add(new BookOwner with {.Name = A.Members("Name").value,
                                       .Books = tryCast(A.Members("Books").value.BaseObject, ArrayList)})
next
```