# capturing Standard Output when executing Powershell C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I trying to execute a simple powershell command in c# and output the result. Powershell v5.1 on Server 2016

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Get-DhcpServerInDC");
Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (PSObject obj in results) {
    sb.AppendLine(obj.ToString()); }
txt_adt_updateTextbox.Text = sb.ToString();
```

But instead of getting a list of DHCP servers and their IP addresses, I get the following.

> DhcpServerInDC DhcpServerInDC DhcpServerInDC DhcpServerInDC
>   DhcpServerInDC DhcpServerInDC DhcpServerInDC DhcpServerInDC
>   DhcpServerInDC DhcpServerInDC DhcpServerInDC DhcpServerInDC
>   DhcpServerInDC

Comment: The nicely formatted list/table you typically see in PowerShell is shown by the host (e.g. console, ISE, etc).  In this case _**you**_ are the host, so you need to do the formatting.  From the documentaion, it looks like you should get back a collection of WMI objects - if you break at `sb.AppendLine...` you'll be able to see what properties there are on `obj` and then you can grab/format as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for that. What would the code be checking those properties though? And does anyone know where there is a reference for the objects for the various powershell commands? I can't seem to find one.

Comment: I figured out how to get the specific info I was looking for, for this specific command. 
(PSObject)obj.Members["DnsName"].Value.ToString()

Comment: @boxdog if you want to put that comment as an answer I'm happy to mark it as correct.

Comment: I've added it as an answer.  I've also included a link to a previous answer of mine that would have saved you some time and effort if I'd remembered it before :-(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nicely formatted list/table you typically see in PowerShell is shown by the host (e.g. console, ISE, etc). In this case *you* are the host, so you need to do the formatting.

From the documentaion, it looks like you should get back a collection of WMI objects.  Use the technique shown in one of my previous answers to get the data you want:

[Dealing with CimObjects with PowerShell inside C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51099688/dealing-with-cimobjects-with-powershell-inside-c-sharp/51103104#51103104)