# How to execute Test-NetConnection in C# application

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-5

I was trying to execute the following code:

```
PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create();
powerShellInstance.AddScript("Test-NetConnection *SomeIPaddress* -port 90");
var result = powerShellInstance.Invoke();
```

result is always empty, I can't figureout why, there is no error, I'm using Cake.Powershell 1.0.1
NuGet package with .NET 5 and PowerShell 5 installed on my Windows 8.1 PC

Is there any other way to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: What does it return if you run it in the terminal?

Comment: I think you should call `Invoke` in the second line after `AddScript`.

Comment: In PowerShell terminal works as expected, I get all the info I need. Adding another Invoke doesn't help...

Comment: Sounds similar to a previous question where the issue was the project's target architecture: [Using PowerShell command “Get-LocalGroup” in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56259580/9529842)

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the Service project I was working on, started a fresh copy,
re-installed the NuGet packages and that did the trick, no idea what
was wrong, sorry I coudn't be more helpful on this one...